# Как записать ключ команды в переменную

Tags: bash

```
export H =`-H ${email} -H ${key}`

curl -X GET $HOST_NAME $H
```

У меня такая запить не работает, как заставить работать **$H**?

Comment: Использовать двойные кавычки.

Comment: @ Alexey Ten   пишет bad variable name

Comment: И пробел перед равно убрать

Comment: нет все равно не работает @Alexey_Ten

Comment: Что не работает? Напишите в начале скрипта `set -x` и смотрите какие команды на самом деле выполняются

Comment: bad variable name пишет

Comment: `export H="-H ${email} -H ${key}"`